# Wordpress: Autofilling Post-Thumbnail

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

Is  there a proper way to fill the Post-Thumbnail automatically? In fact, I ask the Vimeo-Api for an Video-Thumbnail. This task is already done...

But now I need to add the recieved Thumbnail as Post-Thumbnail. So that all depending images sizes are also generated.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this (i didn't test this but it should work, i'm using something similar in a plugin of mine):

```
            $image_path = 'path to your image';
            $id = 'id of corresponding post';
            $title = 'title of your image';

            // Checking the filetype
            $wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype(basename($image_path), null );

            $attachment = array(

               'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
               'post_title' => $title,
               'post_content' => '',
               'post_status' => 'inherit',
               'post_parent' => $id

            );

            // inserting the attachment
            $attach_id=wp_insert_attachment($attachment,$image_path);

            require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');

            // Generating the metadate (and the thumbnails)
            $attach_data=wp_generate_attachment_metadata($attach_id,$image_path );

            // Setting it as thumbnail        
            update_post_meta( $id, '_thumbnail_id', $attach_id );
```